# Communication between two fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm new in android and I would like how to do it. I got an activity and in the activity I got 3 fragments running and visible simultaneously. I would like how can I communicate a class reference of the MiddleFragment to a TopFragment???
Thank you

Comment: By using `Interface`

Comment: mmmm ok. How can I do it?

Comment: Search on _Google_ for that..

Comment: ahah it's easy to answer like this....already done! Nothing interesting!

Comment: What's wrong? [Check this](http://kb4dev.com/tutorial/android-layout/communication-between-fragments-in-android)

Comment: Just one [fragment communication tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&site=&source=hp&q=fragment+communication+tutorial&oq=fragment+commu&gs_l=hp.3.2.0l3.4475.7863.0.9945.15.14.0.0.0.0.201.1733.0j9j2.11.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..5.10.1608.0.VsTmtY6WnCU)

Comment: It seems that with custom views on fragments there are some differences...and this make problems....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For separate fragments, use setTargetFragment() when you create your fragment. The system will properly restore the new target fragment after the Activity is re-created. You can cast the target fragment to an interface to make it cleaner.

If your fragment is a child fragment that needs to communicate with its parent fragment, use getParentFragment() instead.

An alternative way is to send a local broadcast from fragment A that can be listened by fragment B.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty well described in the official docs:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Basically you communicate via Activity that hosts your Fragments.